# Como recuperar valor de atributo data-bind en documento html

Tags: javascript, html

Me surgió la necesidad de obtener algunos valores desde el atributo `data`

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae')}" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com">
```

Pero solo necesito obtener la parte del enlace

```
http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae
```

No tengo idea de como podría ser, si necesitan mas información de lo que se quiere realizar, favor indicarme en los comentarios.

Gracias de antemano y Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante una expresión regular:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const bind = img.getAttribute('data-bind');
const regex = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/;

if (regex.test(bind)) {
  const url = regex.exec(bind)[0];
  console.info(url);
}
```

```html
<img data-bind="attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae')}" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com"/>
```

Comment: buenas gracias por tu respuesta acertada, en caso que quiera extraer mas de un link osea  <img data-bind="attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae')}" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com"/>
 se repite varias veces claro con distinto link

Comment: Tienes que aplicar el mismo procedimiento para cada atributo (`data-bind`, `src`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Si las expresiones regulares te asustan, aquí tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo mas sencillo pero igualmente funcional ;))

```js
$(function (){
 url = $("img").data("bind").split("'")[1];
 console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-bind="attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae')}" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com"/>
```

En el ejemplo uso [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) porque es fácil de usar, multiplataformas y te permite desarrollar mas escribiendo menos.

Ahora te explico: el Método `split` divide un cadena de caracteres en una matriz utilizando para ello un carácter (o cadena) como separador, en el caso que nos planteas seria:

Cadena a convertir:

```
attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae')}" src="http:
//www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com
```

Cadena (o Carácter) usado como separado (o delimitador): `'`

Matriz creada en el proceso de división:

```
0:attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon(
1:http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae
2:)}" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=gamovideo.com
```

Es por ello que cuando ejecutamos: `$("img").data("bind").split("'")[1]`, nos devuelve el indice 1 de la matriz que es en este caso el url: `1:http://gamovideo.com/9tbtyuoti8ae` .

Espero esto te sirva, Saludos!! ;))